# How to get Alfresco Action status

Tags: java, alfresco

I have a problem. I have Alfresco 4. I'm create a rule(for INBOUND, OUTBOUND, UPDATE) and action for my scpecific folder. But when I hook the action in my java class(extending from ActionExecuterAbstractBase) I don't know, how to get status for node(what's happen - deleted, modified or created node). One way for resolved this problem - it's a comparison uploaded_date and modified_date properties from a node. But it's not good. If anyone know how to do it, please, answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways to do this:
1) create 3 classes, which gets triggered by the right type.

2) I would just ad an extra parameter to your action, like status. And at the inbound rule just set inbound, etc. Then you can read the action.getParameterValue (check the [Custom Actions Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Actions)).