# How to get Alfresco rule type for executed action?

Tags: java, alfresco

I found this question with answer in [How to get Alfresco Action status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687676/how-to-get-alfresco-action-status) .

I have a one action executor class, which triggered for inbound & outbound & update rule types. Tahir Malik told that we can add an extra param to action (#2), How I can do this? I didn't found how to get rule type for action executor in runtime.

P.S Rules & actions adding via bootstrap for me.

Regards,
Eugene

====================================

**Update:**

```
<rule:rule view:childName="rule:sampleRule">
...
<view:properties>
  <rule:ruleType>
    <view:values>
      <view:value>inbound</view:value>
      <view:value>update</view:value>
      <view:value>outbound</view:value>
    </view:values>
  </rule:ruleType>
  ...
</view:properties>
<view:associations>
  <rule:action>
    <act:compositeaction view:childName="rule:action">
      ...
      <view:associations>
        <act:actions>
          <act:action view:childName="act:actions">
            <view:properties>
              ... 
              <act:definitionName>myActionBean</act:definitionName>
              <act:executionActionStatus>New</act:executionActionStatus>
            </view:properties>
            ...
          </act:action>
        </act:actions>
        <act:conditions>
          ... // There is condition to check mime type of a node
        </act:conditions>
      </view:associations>
    </act:compositeaction>
  </rule:action>
</view:associations>
```

============================================

**Update2:**

```
<view:reference view:pathref="rule:ruleFolder">
  <view:associations>
    <cm:contains>
      <rule:rule view:childName="rule:inboundRule">
        ...
        <view:properties>
          <rule:ruleType>
            <view:values>
              <view:value>inbound</view:value>
            </view:values>
          </rule:ruleType>
          ...
        </view:properties>
        <view:associations>
          <rule:action>
            <act:compositeaction view:childName="rule:action">
              ...
              <view:properties>
                ...
                <act:definitionName>myActionBean</act:definitionName>
                <act:executionActionStatus>Completed</act:executionActionStatus>
              </view:properties>
              <view:associations>
                <act:actions>
                  <act:action view:childName="act:actions">
                    <view:properties>
                      ...
                    </view:properties>
                    <view:associations>
                      <act:parameters>
                        <act:actionparameter view:childName="act:parameters">
                          <view:properties>
                            <act:parameterName>ruleType</act:parameterName>
                            <act:parameterValue>
                              <view:value view:datatype="d:text">inbound</view:value>
                            </act:parameterValue>
                          </view:properties>
                        </act:actionparameter>
                      </act:parameters>
                    </view:associations>
                  </act:action>
                </act:actions>
                <act:conditions>
                  <act:compositeactioncondition view:childName="act:conditions">
                    <view:properties>
                      <act:definitionName>composite-condition</act:definitionName>
                      <act:or>
                        <view:value view:datatype="d:boolean">true</view:value>
                      </act:or>
                      <act:invert>false</act:invert>
                    </view:properties>
                    <view:associations>
                      <act:compositeconditions>
                        <act:actioncondition view:childName="act:compositeconditions">
                          <view:properties>
                            <act:definitionName>compare-mime-type</act:definitionName>
                            <act:invert>false</act:invert>
                          </view:properties>
                          <view:associations>
                            <act:parameters>
                              <act:actionparameter view:childName="act:parameters">
                                <view:properties>
                                  <act:parameterName>value</act:parameterName>
                                  <act:parameterValue>
                                    <view:value view:datatype="cmis:id">my-first-mimeType</view:value>
                                  </act:parameterValue>
                                </view:properties>
                              </act:actionparameter>
                            </act:parameters>
                          </view:associations>
                        </act:actioncondition>
                        <act:actioncondition view:childName="act:compositeconditions">
                          <view:properties>
                            <act:definitionName>compare-mime-type</act:definitionName>
                            <act:invert>false</act:invert>
                          </view:properties>
                          <view:associations>
                            <act:parameters>
                              <act:actionparameter view:childName="act:parameters">
                                <view:properties>
                                  <act:parameterName>value</act:parameterName>
                                  <act:parameterValue>
                                    <view:value view:datatype="cmis:id">my-second-mimeType</view:value>
                                  </act:parameterValue>
                                </view:properties>
                              </act:actionparameter>
                            </act:parameters>
                          </view:associations>
                        </act:actioncondition>
                      </act:compositeconditions>
                      <act:parameters>
                        <act:actionparameter view:childName="act:parameters">
                          <view:properties>
                            <act:parameterName>orconditions</act:parameterName>
                            <act:parameterValue>
                              <view:value view:datatype="d:boolean">true</view:value>
                            </act:parameterValue>
                          </view:properties>
                        </act:actionparameter>
                      </act:parameters>
                    </view:associations>
                  </act:compositeactioncondition>
                </act:conditions>
              </view:associations>
            </act:compositeaction>
          </rule:action>
        </view:associations>
      </rule:rule>
      ...
    </cm:contains>
  </view:associations>
</view:reference>
```

Comment: Can't you just set a different parameter value for each different way of triggering the action, then when you action runs read that value to see how it was triggered?

Comment: I just added a sample code. I have one rule and one action executor, but it's triggered for all rule types. Where and how I can add a diff param value.

Comment: I can create a 3 rules for each type and add different param value, but I don't like this solution.

Comment: I created a three rules for each rule type but mapped to one action. For each rule I add an action param like: ruleType

Answer (score 0):

I might understand your confusion.
What you need to do is first change your custom Java Action.

Add such a line:

```
protected void executeImpl(Action action, NodeRef actionedUponNodeRef) {

String status= (String) action.getParameterValue("status");
```

Then you need to write a JavaScript file to [trigger the action](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#ScriptAction_API), e.g.:

```
var custom = actions.create("myActionBean");    
custom.parameters.status = "My New Status";
custom.execute(document);
```

And Final, you need to configure a rule which triggers this JavaScript.

You could probably also set the parameter through the bootstrap, but the thing is you've got less control through the bootstrap. And with the JavaScript you can modify it on runtime(new releases).

If you want to send the parameters on bootstrap take a look at this bootstrap file:

> /alfresco/bootstrap/transferTargetRule.xml

Comment: I doesn't have any js triggers. My rules should be triggered by Alfresco. This is what I want:
1) Create a rules for some folder that will be triggered on update/delete/create action for some specific node type.
2) For each action type I will send info to external service, like 
http://example.com?nodeRef=someNodeRef&action=create/update/delete

So I want create one rule for all rule action, and pass some parameter about rule action type but I doesn't know how to do this. I have three rule for each action that pass ruleType for now.

Comment: In "Update2" you can see a rule definition for inbound rule, and I have a similar code for update/outbound rule with different value for "ruleType" variable.